# How to get text to blink in Outlook 2016?

Tags: css, outlook, signature

I've tried an animated gif (Outlook only renders the first panel). I've tried this css option (as signature and as 'Insert HTML as text'):

```
<span class="blinking">lee</span>
<style type="text/css">
 .blinking{
    animation:blinkingText 0.8s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{     color: #000;    }
    49%{    color: transparent; }
    50%{    color: transparent; }
    99%{    color:transparent;  }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}

</style>
```

It has become a running joke that this person keeps referring to me by the wrong name. I've signed my emails with my name as all caps, bold, italics, etc. They never notice.

So I want to try the blinking text option.

thanks!

Comment: you shoud probably be able to use the obsolete `<blink>Lee</blink>` tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink as for a joke, seems fair to me ;)